# Agestore utility in Windows

Tags: windows, command

Does anyone - where can we find this command line utility in Windows  -Agestore

I have some good use cases for this utility

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/agestore-command-line-options

Also happened to blog from from Microsoft today

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230918-35/?p=108789

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/extra-tools) which eventually leads you to the [Windows Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/).